# AES encryption/decryption in android

Tags: android, kotlin, cryptography, base64, aes

I'm trying to use AES for encryption and decryption. so I wore the class with two function each for one:

```kotlin
class Cryptography {

    private var initVector = ByteArray(16)
    init {
        SecureRandom().nextBytes(initVector)
    }

    fun encrypt(input: String, password: String): String {

        val plainText = Base64.decode(input, Base64.NO_WRAP)

        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING")

        val keySpec = SecretKeySpec(password.toByteArray(), "AES")

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, IvParameterSpec(initVector))


        val encrypt = cipher.doFinal(plainText)
        return Base64.encodeToString(encrypt, Base64.NO_WRAP)
    }




    fun decrypt(input: String, password: String): String {

        val cypherText = Base64.decode(input, Base64.NO_WRAP)

        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING")
        val keySpec = SecretKeySpec(password.toByteArray(), "AES")


        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, IvParameterSpec(initVector))


        val decrypt = cipher.doFinal(cypherText)
        return Base64.encodeToString(decrypt, Base64.NO_WRAP)
    }

}
```

and I use them just like this:

```kotlin
        val cryptography = Cryptography()
        val cypher = cryptography.encrypt("testing","1234567891234567")
        Log.i("Log","encrypt:$cypher")
        Log.i("Log","decrypt:${cryptography.decrypt(cypher,"1234567891234567")}")
        Log.i("Log","decrypt:${cryptography.encrypt(cypher,"1234567981234567")}")
```

and the result of log is like below:

```kotlin
I/Log: encrypt:6MyrSsAqePP3o5BDDylfBg==
I/Log: decrypt:testing=
I/Log: decrypt:EQtSQev+offTgNTki/AdyMFMlziBr2h1dCX/J3nVUi4=
```

I have multiple problems:

1. as you can see in the second log, `testing=` should be `testing` and it has an extra `=` character.
2. when I encrypt sentences, all the spaces are removed after decryption.`test text`=>`testtext`
3. some sentences make the app crash with error of `bad base-64`

how can I solve these?

Comment: Your code does not run out of the box, so kindly edit your question and add a full (even not successfully) running minimal example (e.g. your "encrypt(input" is never used. Secondly: you are using AES in CBC mode so you need to pass the same initvector to encrypt AND decrypt - I do not see any IV-declaration.

Comment: the iv is initialized in the init block at the beginning of the class. and the input is converted to a byte array and assigned to plainText /cypherText variables. @MichaelFehr

Comment: Your encryption Base64 decodes the plaintext and your decryption Base64 encodes the decrypted data. But in your test you pass a simple string and not a Base64 encoded string. So either pass a Base64 encoded string or remove the Base64 decoding/encoding of the plaintext (note: the Base64 encoding/decoding of the ciphertext should not be removed).

Answer (score 0):

In your `encrypt()` this line is incorrect:

```
val plainText = Base64.decode(input, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

**It is completely possible that your `input` is not Base64 encoded like your test.** You normally need to do something like this:

```
val plainBuf = input.toByteArray();
```

Similar problem happens at end of `decrypt()`:

```
return Base64.encodeToString(decrypt, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

which should be something like:

```
return String(decrypt)
```

As a side note, you will probably encounter another problem soon because of your IV. You need to have similar IV for encryption/decryption. But from your code I can assume that you don't send IV from encryption to decryption.

Comment: The Base64 encoding/decoding is not wrong in general. It is just that test data and code do not match. The code is OK if Base64 encoded data is passed (e.g. in case of binary data which is not UTF8 decodable). Here a UTF8 encoding would be an overhead. Also, you should use Kotlin snippets.

Comment: @user9014097 yea, but it is really abnormal to try and encrypt a Base64 string. Because it means that you have created around 30% redundant data for encryption when it is not needed. After encryption, Base64 encoding is used in a lot of cases because it will be easier to send (for example over network, save in a JSON,  or other text based structures), although it is not necessary too. And about snippets, sorry, I don't know Kotlin syntax exactly. Will be great if you can update it with Kotlin syntax.

Comment: In the case of arbitrary binary data, which is often Base64 encoded (because it is not UTF8 encodable) exactly what you warn about happens. Without Base64 decoding before encryption you unnecessarily encrypt the Base64 overhead. The implementation seems to me to be intended for such a case and is therefore not wrong _in principle_. It probably just doesn't fit to the use case of the OP which uses simple strings as input/test data that can be directly UTF8 encoded (but will be adjusted accordingly by your fix).